# Шаблон (файл манифеста) не даёт приложению на андроид запускаться

Tags: android, c++, qt, mobile-development

Проблема следующего толка: сделал рабочее приложение, которое прекрасно запускалось на устройстве; решил сменить название приложению; прочитал про файл манифеста; узнал, как его можно сделать, сделал, но это всё испортило: как бы я дальше не шаманил с настройками этого файла манифеста (в том числе и с именем) при запуске на устройстве выдаёт: "Ваше приложение столкнулось с фатальной ошибкой и не может более работать". Думаю на параметры минимального и целевого SDK, так как с ними было что-то мутное: они не были указаны, но компилятор всё равно ругался на то, что выбранный SDK ниже требуемого.

Для чистоты экспириенса я создал чистый проект под Android, всё прекрасно запустилось на устройстве. Но стоило мне добавить файл манифеста (и изменить имя с иконкой), как всё пошло по уже озвученному сценарию.

Что делать? Как мне изменить имя приложению, не сталкиваясь при этом с подобными проблемами?

При необходимости могу скинуть XML-код файла манифеста

[image: Вот скриншот файла манифеста:]

Answer (score 0):

Что значит добавил файл манифеста? Он есть в каждом приложении и без него ничего не работало бы. Получается у вас теперь два манифеста в проекте. Ищите оригинальный и правьте его, а тот который добавили сами, удалите.

Comment: Ничего страшного, если он у меня лежит в директории сборки?

Comment: Надеюсь, всё получится

Comment: Манифест должен лежать в src/main

Comment: Скажу честно, у меня в папке проекта только исходники и мои собственные файлы, без подпапок

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение:
Надо выставить минимальный SDK на 21, а целевой на 29. Но это не главное, как по мне.
Главное: установить код версии (например 1) и название версии (главное сделать это в таком формате: 1.0.0.0).
После этого всё будет работать, как надо.

Думаю, дело было всё же в названии версии и неверном формате.